# Besides Iran, are there any other countries which have held referendums to determine the future political system with only one candidate?

Tags: iran, political-system, referendum

On 30-31 March, 1979 a [referendum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1979_Iranian_Islamic_Republic_referendum) was held in Iran to determine the political system of the country (Previously the monarchial regime had been overthrown on February 11, 1979).

But the problem with that referendum was that it was not standard. It just had one candidate (e.g. Islamic Republic) and people had to vote either yes or no to that single choice. In other words, other political systems that were representating many people weren't allowed to participate in the process so that the candidate remains the sole opponent of itself in the dictatorship. As a result, above 98% of the voters (with a turnout of above 90%) decided to say yes because there was a huge propaganda advocating the Islamic Republic and also it wasn't clear what would have happened next if they had chosen to say no. Also, the color of ballots (green for Yes, red for No) had a psychological impact on the voters.

**My question**: Is Iran alone? Are there any other countries besides Iran that have held a referendum to determine the political system of the country after the collapse of the previous one, but only with one choice available?

**Update**: I'm seeing answerers are making examples of constitutional bill referendums. While constitutional bill referendums do ratificate the political system of the country, it wasn't the case for Iranian referendum. They just asked people to ratificate the political system. A constitutional bill referendum took place in Iran in 1989 (10 years after the revolution). So I think Iran might be still alone in holding a referndum to choose the political system, and a constitutional bill referendum so many years after it. In other countries these referendums are collected in one constitutional bill referendum.

Comment: Lots of referendums are single question with Yes or No the only answers. The referendum by Britain to leave the EU; the previous one to join the EU; the referendum on Quebec independence. As for narrowing it down to referendums about choosing a political system - how many of those do you think there have been?

Comment: It doesn't matter if there have been a lot of or a few such a referendum. What matters is that when you organize such a referendum you should include several potential political systems in it, not just one. And I know about single question referendums with Yes or No the only answers. But they are not the case in my question.

Comment: "You should include several potential political systems in it." Why? When these referendums happen, the details of the political system have already been agreed and what they want is ratification. Ironing out these details for a single system is difficult, agreeing on several different competing systems would be next to impossible. And then, the details *do matter*. Perhaps I prefer a Republic to a Monarchy, but a Monarchy with lots of personal freedoms to a Republic with fewer personal freedom. The "they must chose between several options" premise is not as evident as you think.

Comment: Given that the referendum in your example was 99% in favour, what would be the point in introducing a variety of choices for the 1% to choose between?

Comment: @DJClayworth First of all, people of Iran were manipulated to believe Islamic Republic is the best choice. Second, there was that high percentage in favor because of that manipulation and because people thought it's better than nothing to choose Islamic Republic. If other political systems were allowed to enter the race the outcome would be so smaller for Islamic Republic in percent.

Comment: @DJClayworth The 99% in favor was because the other choice besides a Yes to Islamic Republic was a "No" to it. And you know, a no has a blurry future in the case of choosing the kind of political system.

Comment: Your comment makes no sense. If people had wanted something other than an Islamic Republic then they would have voted No. Your last sentence is gibberish.

Answer (score 5):

A constitutional referendum was held in Bangladesh on 15 September 1991. Voters were asked "**Should or not the President assent to the Constitution (Twelfth Amendment) Bill, 1991 of the People's Republic of Bangladesh?**" The amendments would lead to the reintroduction of parliamentary government, with the President becoming the constitutional head of state, but the Prime Minister the executive head. It also abolished the position of vice-president and would see the President elected by Parliament.

The result saw 83.6% vote in favour, with a turnout of 35.2%.

Comment: Good answer. Mali, Tunisia and Central African Republic all had yes/no constitutional referendums recently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what I asked about was a referendum to choose the political system after overthrowning the previous regime. I'm not seeking a yes/no referendum of other causes.

Comment: @SnackExchange Agreeing to a constitution pretty much is choosing a political system.

Comment: @DJClayworth Well, people of Iran agreed to the constitution 10 years after the 1979 referendum

Comment: There can be other ways of choosing a political system, but choosing a constitution is definitely one. But I'm beginning to think you are here for an argument, not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Also, [the Referendum of the Spanish Constitution of 1978](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1978_Spanish_constitutional_referendum).

Really, your question seems based on the premise that this kind of situation are the exception and not the norm, but you are wrong.

Comment: But the Iranian referendum lacked a voting for the constitution bill. It just asked people to ratificate the kind of political system. The referendum to ratificate the constitution bill took place in 1989 (10 years after the revolution). Is it also a norm?!

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it's actually very common for *referendums* to be a simple Yes/No option.

So-called votes of confidence (in an incumbent regime) also tend to work the same way - Yes or No. Clearly, such votes can "determine the future political system".

I think you're inclined to analyse the Iranian referendum as an ersatz liberal election, designed to express an option between pre-selected candidates for high office, and therefore querying why only one candidate exists on the ballot.

A Yes/No referendum is actually far more democratically powerful - it's capable of expressing rejection of a particular regime, without the voter being forced to endorse any other pre-selected candidate (and without any specific alternative being pre-ordained by the result of the referendum).

It's also worth noting that under liberal regimes, the multiple candidates on a ballot are often carbon-copies politically, so even though there are multiple candidates in a ballot, there is typically only one politics on offer (with alternative candidates assaulted using rich liberal ownership of the media and their selective release of information). The only difference is you can't even vote "No" in liberal elections. So it's not actually that unusual for a ballot to have only one political option.

With 90% turnout and 98% approval, the Iranian referendum would seem far more decisive than the average liberal election - where a candidate may attain or retain high office with say 30% of the electorate on a 30% turnout.

Comment: But aren't *all* people important? A percentage of people tend to like a republic. Another percentage like a constitutional monarchy, and so on. So if we put just one option on the ballot for people to vote for the future political system we are practically ignoring other people who dislike that kind of political system. A Yes/No referendum is good, but not when it's about choosing a political system.

Comment: And the reason for high percentages of turnout and in favour, was simply the fact that people tend to like their revolution and their new leaders. But if another Yes/No referendum to approve/disapprove Islamic Republic was going to be held tomorrow I bet its result would be at most 10% approval.

Comment: Example of good Yes/No referendum: Should UK leave the European Union? Well, in this case **all** British people are divided to those who like the idea and those who dislike the idea. Now, a bad Yes/No referendum: Should Islamic Republic be the political system of Iran? Well, in this case all people are divided to those who like the idea and those who dislike it. **But** in this case, the people who dislike the idea also are divided to like other political systems which **represent** them. Many people said yes in that referendum because it wasn't clear what happens next if they had said no.

Comment: @SnackExchange, if you don't like the current regime (or the singular regime offered), you'd simply vote "No". Whilst that doesn't immediately answer what will replace it, it does seem to imply the demise of the rejected regime. So those who don't want the regime in question, are hardly "ignored". I do agree with you though that the Iranian ref was probably held as a show of strength when their popularity was beyond question, not to actually decide or resolve a political question.

Comment: They were ignored because their representative political systems weren't present in the process. Maybe with presence of multiple choices Islamic Republic would lose.

Comment: @SnackExchange, alternative systems are represented by the option "No". Clearly, there would have to be subsequent activity to resolve between several alternatives, but that doesn't mean those alternatives aren't represented at all. Most liberal regimes (who hold ballots in the manner you seem to think is more representative) would be thrown into immediate crisis if a Yes/No referendum were held, and all their opponents were represented by "No".

Comment: A standard referendum for choosing the political system should have all the available options on the ballot. Just make an example that a non-authoritarian regime has held that non-standard referendum to choose a political system! Also, if you choose to hold a Yes/No referendum to choose a political system (like what Iran did) you are practically putting words in people's mouths.

Comment: Also, by mentioning "represent" I don't mean representation of options on the ballot. I meant represntation of people. Islamic Republic wasn't representating many people, and they had the right to have their political system of interest on the ballot. Also, by representating all opponents by a "No" option, those opponents are simply minimized and dumped.

Comment: @SnackExchange, it's impossible to represent all possible choices, such that a "none" option does not cover something additional to all other specific options. As for "putting words in people's mouths", how does a liberal regime differ when it offers only one kind of politics on the ballot (perhaps through two or more candidates), *without* an option to choose "No"?

Comment: And choosing the "No" option is not a dumping ground. If the majority choose "No", then they are clearly against the current offering. What exactly they are for would have to be further determined (and indeed, there would have to be further clarification of what happens when a majority cannot agree on anything). But the existence of a multi-stage process is not inherently illegitimate. A Yes/No referendum on a current regime, is actually more democratically expressive than the typical liberal ballot, where you can't say No, and you're either forced to choose what you're given, or to boycott.

Comment: If it was impossible to represent all possible choices they could at least have put top 5 political systems (based on a survey which of course didn't happen) instead of stalking people with a single choice.

Comment: A referendum should have a clear future whether the majority of people choose yes or no. If it has a blurry future with any of the options that's not a standard referendum. And Iranian referendum had a blurry future with a "no" outcome.

Comment: A Yes/No referendum to choose a political system makes sense when the **current regime** holds it (of course it's impossible). Because it should be first cleared that people approve the current regime or not. And if most of people say no, then the main referendum is held after overthrowning of the current regime with **multiple choices**. But if a Yes/No referendum to choose a political system is held after overthrowning of the current regime, it simply doesn't make sense. Because the country lacks a political system in this case.

Comment: @SnackExchange, a referendum is not a single choice. It's a binary choice: accept or reject. I accept that "No" may have been somewhat uncertain, and doesn't allow people to consider what all the consequences might be. But a multi-choice election (with or without a "none" option) doesn't allow people to consider what all the consequences might be either - for example, the consequences of a "split vote", or of political betrayal following the election.

Comment: Not all referendums are Yes/No. Also I think you think I say the choices should be humans in choosing political systems which is wrong! The choices should be the names of kinds of political systems. Also, I meant the sole political system offered by single choice.

Comment: @SnackExchange, not every variant of a political system necessarily has a different (and widely recognised) name.

Comment: But the famous ones do. Republic, Constitutional Monarchy, Federal Republic, Parliamentary Republic, Socialist Republic, etc.

Comment: @SnackExchange, the devil can be in the detail with these things. But I maintain a Yes/No referendum doesn't mean only one political system is offered. If the waiter comes to you and asks "would Sir like a slice of cake, or would Sir like something else?", you wouldn't say you're being forced to eat cake only.